# Google Cloud Function HTTP Trigger

Tags: flask, google-cloud-functions, url-parameters

I am trying to give arguments to my function by adding URL parameter.

```
import json
import flask
def location_sort(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    location = json.dumps(request_json)
    location = json.loads(location)
    reverse_location = {v: k for k, v in location.items()}

    x = location.keys()
    harf_x = (float(max(x)) + float(min(x))) / 2 

    y_right = []
    y_left = []
    sorted_location = [] 

    for i in location:
        if float(i) < harf_x:
            y_left.append(location[i])
        else: 
            y_right.append(location[i])

    y_left.sort() 
    y_right.sort(reverse=True) 

    sorted_input = y_left + y_right 


    for i in sorted_input:
        sorted_location.append([reverse_location[i], i])
    for i in sorted_location:
        i[0],i[1] = float(i[0]),float(i[1])
    return sorted_location

def cal_centroid(location):
    area = 0 # 면적
    centroid_x = 0 
    centroid_y = 0 
    temp = 0

    for i in range(len(location)):
        if i == len(location)-1: 
            temp = location[i][0]*location[0][1] - location[0][0]*location[i][1] 
            area += temp*0.5
            centroid_x += (location[i][0] + location[0][0]) * temp
            centroid_y += (location[i][1] + location[0][1]) * temp
        else:
            temp = location[i][0]*location[i+1][1] - location[i+1][0]*location[i][1]
            area += temp*0.5
            centroid_x += (location[i][0] + location[i+1][0]) * temp
            centroid_y += (location[i][1] + location[i+1][1]) * temp

    centroid_x = round(centroid_x / (6*area), 6)
    centroid_y = round(centroid_y / (6*area), 6)
    x = [centroid_x, centroid_y]
    return json.dumps(x)
def main(request):
    request_args = request.args
    if request_args and "location" in request_args:
        request = request["location"]
        request = json.dumps(request)
        a = location_sort(request)
        return cal_centroid(a)
```

This is my code for Cloud Function and i run main function. And i tried the URL as

```
https://<REGION>-<GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT>.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME?location={"37.284213":"127.006481","37.562045":"127.034809","37.528694":"126.907483","37.411124":"127.124356"}
```

And it returns

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

What could be the problem to my code? I am very beginner for GCF and i would be very thankful for your help:)

Comment: How are you calling the url? Are you authenticated?
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http

Comment: Thanks but i solved the problem.